# Renting a house on a tourist visa in the UK

Tags: tourist-visas, rental

I need to provide proof of address. So the best way is to hire a house or a flat.

I have a UK tourist visa. Am I eligible to rent a house while I am in UK, so that I can get a proof of address?

I will not live in the UK, and will go back to my country. I am just trying to rent to get a proof of of address. So I am looking for a short-term rental if possible as a tourist.

Comment: "Rent" is a complicated word. Are you talking about a very short term let, or something longer term? Note that if the property is going to be your "main home", the landlord has a duty to check your "right to rent" which isn't going to extend outside the validity period of your visa https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/573057/6_1193_HO_NH_Right-to-Rent-Guidance.pdf

Comment: Where are you being asked to provide proof? Application for a UK Standard Visitor visa does not require that and, if you already have been issued a visa (*I have a UK tourist visa*), then who is asking for this information?

Comment: @Giorgio this is not for visa application. I am in uk by tourist visa already. A company requests proof of address. So I thought to rent a flat or house to get proof of address. But I am not sure a tourist can rent or not. They can rent car though.

Comment: @origimbo thanks I thought to get the proof of address by renting a flat or house so that I can get the paper. Of course short term is better for cost reasons. The long enough to get the proof of address is enough for me. But I am not sure if there are limits for renting as time range. I will not live in the uk. After renting and getting the paper I will leave uk. Flat can stay empty. But according to your web link i can only hire for max of 6 months. After providing the proof of address I hope they do not request another one. So maybe 6 months renting would be enough

Comment: It sounds like you want to provide a proof of address for a place you don't legitimately live, seeing as you only want to be there long enough to obtain proof. While I sympathize, I suspect that whoever wants the address proof would not consider that acceptable.

Comment: Thanks Zach but what is the difference if someone leaves in Uk but later has to go abroad as expat. Does this make it unacceptable for the previous applications?

Comment: @Roser Which company wants this proof of address? Is this a company you work for that wants to know if you are living in the UK? Is it a British company?

Comment: If you’re looking for proof of address for eg a bank account or a credit/store card, or a supplier of goods on credit, you’ll typically need to have lived there for a specific minimum period and/or be on the local voters roll or council record.

Answer (score 2):

Under UK law, you may be able to find a private landlord willing to offer a short-term rental. Landlords are required to make a [right-to-rent check](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/573057/6_1193_HO_NH_Right-to-Rent-Guidance.pdf), verifying an individual's status in the country. Under such circumstances, they're likely to require full payment for the entirety of the rental, as well as a security deposit (an amount equal to one or more month's rent).

Reference: [UK.Gov Check your tenant's right to rent](https://www.gov.uk/check-tenant-right-to-rent-documents/how-to-check)

Comment: Is there any time limits on tenancy? Because my tourist visa covers only 6 month, is it possible to hire less than 6 months legally?